# Can I use Amplify.js in the same way that I use localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, polyfills

Has anyone here ever used Amplify.js for localstorage fallback on non HTML5 browsers?. I need to know if you can use it in the same way that you would localstorage for example can I get the size of my localstorage by using the length object eg `amplify.store.length` also can I step tru my localstorage with amplify.js via each key say for eg. `amplify.store.key(i)` where i is a number which is the index of the items stored?

Answer (score 1):

amplify.store is an abstraction over synchronous persistent storage, so it intentionally does not have the same API as localStorage. If you don't provide any parameters, then you will get back an object of all key/value pairs, which you can loop over to solve both of your needs.

```
var key,
    count = 0,
    data = amplify.store();
for ( key in data ) {
    // calculate the count
    count++;
    // or do something with the data
    console.log( key, "is", data[ key ] );
}
console.log( "There are", count, "items in the store." );
```

Comment: ok I may just use cookies as a fall back instead I thought I didnt have to write any new code.